# form validation using javascript,if the enter values are not valid the input field has to show alert using css

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend

```
//app.js


let form2=document.getElementById("form");
let userName2=document.getElementById("userName");


form2.addEventListener("submit",(e)=>{
    e.preventDefault();
    validateInputs();
  })


  function validateInputs(){
    let userNameVal=userName2.value.trim();

    if(userNameVal === ""){
        setError(userName2,"user name is required");
      }
      else{
        setSuccess(userName2);  
      }
  }
function setError(element,message){
  let inputGroup=element.parentElement;
  let errorElement=inputGroup.querySelector("small");
  errorElement.innerText=message;
  inputGroup.classList.add("error");
  inputGroup.classList.remove("success");
}

function setSuccess(element){
  let inputGroup=element.parentElement;
  let errorElement=inputGroup.querySelector("small");
  errorElement.innerText="";
  inputGroup.classList.add("success");
  inputGroup.classList.remove("error");









//css style



.text-box{
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    position: relative;
    
}
 .text-box input{ 
    width: 70%;
    display: block;
   margin-left: 60px;
   font-size: 16px;
   margin-top: 5px;
   padding: 10px;
   border-radius: 6px;
}
.text-box input:focus{
    outline: none;
    border:1px solid rgb(238, 86, 238);
}
.text-box.success input{
    border:1px solid rgb(3, 101, 10);
}
.text-box.error input{
    border-color: rgb(205, 20, 4);
} 

.text-box i{
    visibility:hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top:40px;
    right:90px;

}
.text-box.success i.fa-circle-check{
    visibility: visible;
    color: rgb(3, 101, 10);
}
.text-box.error i.fa-circle-exclamation{
    visibility: visible;
    color: rgb(205, 20, 4);
}
.text-box small{
    color: red;
    position: absolute;
    visibility: hidden;
    left: 0;
    bottom:0;
}
.text-box.error small{
    visibility: visible;
}
#submit{
background-color: burlywood;
color: white;
border: 1px solid black;
border-radius: 5px;
padding: 10px;
cursor: pointer;
font-size: 18px;
padding: 10px;
margin-left: 320px;
margin-top: 10px;

}

//index.html


<section class="formContainer">

            <form class="form" id="form">
                <h1>Student Form</h1>
                <div class="text-box">
                    <label for="userName">User Name</label>
                    <input type="text" id="userName" name="userName">
                    <i class="fas fa-circle-check"></i>
                    <i class="fas fa-circle-exclamation"></i>
                    <small>Please enter a user Name</small>
                </div>



                <input type="button" id="submit" value="REGISTER">
            </form>
        </section>
```

hi, i try to validate the form, i just include one input field with one button ,if user enter the username and click the register button ,the input field border has to change into green and should show the check icon in green and if the user not enter username and click the register button the input field shoud turn into red and has to show the exclamation mark in red and should show the error message in small tag,But i'm not getting any of it

please reply these code and make me clear

Comment: There's a lot of things to do with your code. Also, you can't just do it with css. You need to call it's style and attributes in *js* so it will enable and use the styles from your css. I give you [this scratch](https://codepen.io/neyubee/pen/YzROYzK) so you can understand what I'm trying to say.

Answer (score 1):

Your input type is button. 'button' type does not listen to an action.'Submit'  type  listens to an action.'Register' button is present but has incorrect type="button".it should change to type="submit" to enable form submission.

Answer (score 0):

To ensure the form's submit event is listened to, you should replace the  element with a  element using type="submit" and remove the `<input>` tag and use `<button>` instead

```js
let form2=document.getElementById("form");
let userName2=document.getElementById("userName");


form2.addEventListener("submit",(e)=>{
    e.preventDefault();
    validateInputs();
  })


  function validateInputs(){
    let userNameVal=userName2.value.trim();

    if(userNameVal === ""){
        setError(userName2,"user name is required");
      }
      else{
        setSuccess(userName2);  
      }
  }
function setError(element,message){
  let inputGroup=element.parentElement;
  let errorElement=inputGroup.querySelector("small");
  errorElement.innerText=message;
  inputGroup.classList.add("error");
  inputGroup.classList.remove("success");
}

function setSuccess(element){
  let inputGroup=element.parentElement;
  let errorElement=inputGroup.querySelector("small");
  errorElement.innerText="";
  inputGroup.classList.add("success");
  inputGroup.classList.remove("error");
  }
```

```css
.text-box{
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    position: relative;
    
}
 .text-box input{ 
    width: 70%;
    display: block;
   margin-left: 60px;
   font-size: 16px;
   margin-top: 5px;
   padding: 10px;
   border-radius: 6px;
}
.text-box input:focus{
    outline: none;
    border:1px solid rgb(238, 86, 238);
}
.text-box.success input{
    border:1px solid rgb(3, 101, 10);
}
.text-box.error input{
    border-color: rgb(205, 20, 4);
} 

.text-box i{
    visibility:hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top:40px;
    right:90px;

}
.text-box.success i.fa-circle-check{
    visibility: visible;
    color: rgb(3, 101, 10);
}
.text-box.error i.fa-circle-exclamation{
    visibility: visible;
    color: rgb(205, 20, 4);
}
.text-box small{
    color: red;
    position: absolute;
    visibility: hidden;
    left: 0;
    bottom:0;
}
.text-box.error small{
    visibility: visible;
}
#submit{
background-color: burlywood;
color: white;
border: 1px solid black;
border-radius: 5px;
padding: 10px;
cursor: pointer;
font-size: 18px;
padding: 10px;
margin-left: 320px;
margin-top: 10px;

}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.0/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-iecdLmaskl7CVkqkXNQ/ZH/XLlvWZOJyj7Yy7tcenmpD1ypASozpmT/E0iPtmFIB46ZmdtAc9eNBvH0H/ZpiBw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
</head>
<body>
<section class="formContainer">

            <form class="form" id="form">
                <h1>Student Form</h1>
                <div class="text-box">
                    <label for="userName">User Name</label>
                    <input type="text" id="userName" name="userName">
                    <i class="fas fa-circle-check"></i>
                    <i class="fas fa-circle-exclamation"></i>
                    <small>Please enter a user Name</small>
                </div>



                <button type="submit" id="submit" value="REGISTER">REGISTER</button>
            </form>
        </section>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: yeah ,thank you so much mam,now its working .can i ask one more question,the icons are not visible when it  get error or success,why?

Comment: Either you have not imported the font-awesome cdn for icons or you might be using the icon which is not available in the imported cdn's version

Comment: I have updated the code, and included the font-awesome's cdn. You need to add little bit styling to the code. If this is the answer to your question, mark it as accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating your own validation you should use the build-in validation. Set the required attribute on the input element and optionally the pattern attribute (here I set the pattern to `[a-z0-9_]*`, so it validates on usernames with lowercase letters, numbers and underscore). Now, you can use the `invalid` event to find out when something is invalid. I just set the class name for the input element, because the "feedback" elements (the `<i>`s and `<small>`) are [general siblings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_combinator) to the input element. When something is entered into the input element the validity changes and the class names are removed/added as needed.

Notice that the useCapture parameter is set to true on the addEventListener for the invalid event and `e.preventDefault();` is called in the callback function. This is to stop the event from displaying the default message now that the input has the required attribute.

```js
let form2 = document.forms.form01;


form2.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log('submitting...');
});

form2.addEventListener("invalid", (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  e.target.classList.remove('valid');
  e.target.classList.add('invalid');
}, true);

form2.addEventListener("input", (e) => {
  e.target.classList.remove('invalid');
  e.target.classList.remove('valid');
  if(e.target.validity.valid){
    e.target.classList.add('valid');
  }
});
```

```css
.text-box {
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  position: relative;
}

.text-box input {
  width: 70%;
  display: block;
  margin-left: 60px;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 6px;
}

.text-box input:focus {
  outline: none;
  border: 1px solid rgb(238, 86, 238);
}

input.valid {
  border: 1px solid rgb(3, 101, 10);
}

input.invalid {
  border-color: rgb(205, 20, 4);
}

.text-box i {
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
  right: 90px;
}

.text-box.success i.fa-circle-check {
  visibility: visible;
  color: rgb(3, 101, 10);
}

.text-box.error i.fa-circle-exclamation {
  visibility: visible;
  color: rgb(205, 20, 4);
}

.text-box small {
  color: red;
  position: absolute;
  visibility: hidden;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.text-box.error small {
  visibility: visible;
}

input.invalid~small{
  visibility: visible;
}

input.invalid~i.fa-circle-exclamation{
  visibility: visible;
}

input.valid~i.fa-circle-check{
  visibility: visible;
}

form button {
  background-color: burlywood;
  color: white;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-left: 320px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<section class="formContainer">
  <form class="form" name="form01">
    <h1>Student Form</h1>
    <div class="text-box">
      <label for="userName">User Name</label>
      <input type="text" id="userName" name="userName" pattern="[a-z0-9_]*" required>
      <i class="fas fa-circle-check">✅</i>
      <i class="fas fa-circle-exclamation">⛔</i>
      <small>Please enter a user Name</small>
    </div>
    <button type="submit">Register</button>
  </form>
</section>
```